# What's the best way to design this screen (like note addition in Momento app)?

Tags: iphone, uiview, uiviewcontroller

I would like to create a page similar to the one where the user can add a note in the Momento app (screenshot below).

[image]

What's the best way to structure the View Controllers for this page? There is a tab-like menu in the center of the page. On the top half of the screen, is a view; and at the bottom-half, you get a keyboard (when entering text).

**MY NEED** : entering a note which can have three types of text (so three tabs) and a picture -> so four tabs in all.

On some analysis, goggle'ing, and thinking, I can think of these possibilities:

**OPTION 1**
A TabBarController with 4 tabs (but then I wouldn't be able to place the tab in the middle of the screen like in Momento app & I read (in some Stackoverflow discussions) that Apple guidelines don't recommend changing the tab bar from its natural position either.

**OPTION 2**
Have a view controller, say MyController. This will have 4 buttons (arranged next to each other in the middle of the screen, so that they appear like tabs).
Have one UIView object for the top-half of the page.
Have another UIView object for the bottom-half of the page.

Based on which of the four buttons is selected, I vary the content displayed in the top & bottom UIView objects.

Option 2 sounds good to me. But, I wanted to get an opinion on if it's correct, or is there some better way to achieve this? Thoughts please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, here is where I would start. Two issues; the tabBar and handling the keyboard.  The rest is just pushing a popping appropriate view controllers.

The TabBar:  First Apple has some example code that deals with the Keyboard Accessory component which is probably how Momento renders their tabBarController like thingie.  Here is the [link](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/KeyboardAccessory/Introduction/Intro.html). Their example handles the keyboard in a 'one off' way, unique to this particular app.

The Keyboard:  As for a more generic approach to handing the keyboard, you may want to look at Michael Tyson's TPKeyboardAvoiding component on github.  Here's the [link](https://github.com/michaeltyson/TPKeyboardAvoiding) for that one. The TPKeyboardAvoiding is quite nice in that it is a drop in component that handles keyboard issues for UITableView as well as UIScrollView.

One thing I haven't checked is if Mike's stuff is smart enough to handle the extra height on the Keyboard when it has an Accessory attached.  (It's pretty smart though...).

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 2):

You should use a `UITextView` and set it's `inputView` as a view with those buttons. It should  automatically slide with the keyboard just as you want it.

Hope this helps.

Cheers!